# Backend not loading into browser because of body-parser - server.js

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have a problem with loading my backend server. It runs in terminal, but doesn't run in browser. I don't see where is the problem, I'm new to backend programming. It also worked until I put app.post method, before that it worked with app.use and now, when I remove app.post it still won't work. I just discovered it's because I'm using body-parser, but I still don't know how to fix the problem

Here's the code:

server.js:

```
const app = require("./backend/app");
const debug = require("debug")("node-angular");
const http = require("http");

const normalizePort = val => {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
};

const onError = error => {
  if (error.syscall !== "listen") {
    throw error;
  }
  const bind = typeof port === "string" ? "pipe " + port : "port " + port;
  switch (error.code) {
    case "EACCES":
      console.error(bind + " requires elevated privileges");
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case "EADDRINUSE":
      console.error(bind + " is already in use");
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
};

const onListening = () => {
  const addr = server.address();
  const bind = typeof port === "string" ? "pipe " + port : "port " + port;
  debug("Listening on " + bind);
};

const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || "3000");
app.set("port", port);
console.log(port);
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.on("error", onError);
server.on("listening", onListening);
server.listen(port);
```

app.js

```
And the infinite loop I get: 
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  ); 
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  );
  next();
});

app.post("/api/posts", (req, res, next) => {
  const post = req.body;
  console.log(post);
  res.status(201).json({
    message: "Post added successfully",
  });
});

app.use("/api/posts", (req, res, next) => {
  const posts = [
    {
      id: "fadf12421l",
      title: "First server-side post",
      content: "Ovo dolazi sa servera",
    },
    {
      id: "ksajflaj123",
      title: "Second server-side post",
      content: "Ovo dolazi sa servera",
    },
  ];
  res.status(200).json({
    message: "Posts fetched successfully!",
    posts: posts,
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

And the infinite loop i get:
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLlm5.png)

And in terminal, it works:
[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TNhr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to access localhost:3000, it will come to your GET "/" route. You don't have any route like this, so you have the error.

Try localhost:3000/api/posts from your browser, the block `app.use("/api/posts"...` will be executed

---

**EDIT**

To fix the error about bodyParser, you need to replace `app.use(bodyParser.json);` by `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: It still doesn't work, body-parser is blocking it. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Replace `app.use(bodyParser.json);` by `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: If you find my answer is helpful, you can mark it as accepted

Comment: I did, it just wouldn't let me do that immediately :)